# Gitlab and redmine high memory usage

Tags: ruby, redmine, gitlab

I have a VPS with 1GB memory, Debian 7 stable, Gitlab and Redmine installed without anything else (except normal processes).

This configuration consumes more than 900MB of memory. I already set unicorn workers to 1 but no significant changes. Version of Redmine is 2.5.1.stable, version of Gitlab is 6-9-stable.

I wonder if there a way to reduce the memory consuption and CPU load. I might use nginx instead of apache2 or postgres instead of mysql. What else?

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Here is the list of running processes:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2  30176  2160 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:38   0:00 [kthreadd/1723]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:38   0:00 [khelper/1723]
root       227  0.0  0.0  16988   884 ?        S    10:38   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge  --daemon
root       235  0.0  0.1  21300  1352 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       283  0.0  0.0  21296  1024 ?        S    10:38   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       284  0.0  0.0  21296  1028 ?        S    10:38   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       428  0.0  0.0  14936   640 ?        S    10:38   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root      1874  0.0  0.1  58740  1652 ?        Sl   10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
root      1920  0.0  0.0  57568   988 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 2
root      1922  0.0  0.0  57568   632 ?        S    10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 2
root      1988  0.0  0.2  72552  2648 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 sendmail: MTA: accepting connections          
root      2029  0.0  0.1  49888  1244 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      2061  0.0  0.0  19520   964 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/xinetd -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid -stayalive -inetd_compat -inetd_ipv6
root      2113  0.0  2.1 301048 22244 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      2156  0.0  0.0  20364  1044 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root      2206  0.0  0.0   4136   712 ?        S    10:38   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
root      2322  0.0  0.1  23368  1968 ?        Ssl  10:38   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root      2337  0.5  0.2 100600  2652 ?        Sl   10:38   0:19 PassengerHelperAgent
root      2348  0.0  0.9  46372 10412 ?        Sl   10:38   0:00 Passenger spawn server                                                                                 
nobody    2353  0.0  0.3  81832  4168 ?        Sl   10:38   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
mysql     2551  0.0  5.2 464312 55360 ?        Sl   10:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysq
root      2552  0.0  0.0   4044   668 ?        S    10:38   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
root      2684  0.0  0.7  58116  8300 ?        S    10:38   0:00 python /usr/sbin/denyhosts --daemon --purge --config=/etc/denyhosts.conf
redis     2708  0.0  0.1  39964  1676 ?        Ssl  10:38   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
git       2811  0.5 13.0 377628 136484 ?       Sl   10:38   0:19 unicorn_rails master -D -c /home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb -E production                            
git       2846  0.0 12.3 377628 129148 ?       Sl   10:38   0:00 unicorn_rails worker[0] -D -c /home/git/gitlab/config/unicorn.rb -E production                         
git       2873  0.6 13.6 428528 143532 ?       Sl   10:38   0:23 sidekiq 2.17.0 gitlab [0 of 25 busy]                                                                   
root      2892  0.0  0.2  32712  2248 ?        Ss   10:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 106:111
root      2913  0.0  0.0  14532   876 tty1     Ss+  10:38   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 console
root      2915  0.0  0.0  14532   880 tty2     Ss+  10:38   0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
admin     2976  0.1  8.6 265444 90444 ?        Sl   10:39   0:03 Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /var/www/redmine                                                         
admin     2984  0.0  9.8 282032 103736 ?       Sl   10:39   0:00 Rails: /var/www/redmine                                                                                
admin     2992  0.0  8.1 265444 85744 ?        Sl   10:39   0:00 Rails: /var/www/redmine                                                                                
admin     2998  0.0  8.1 265444 85764 ?        Sl   10:39   0:00 Rails: /var/www/redmine                                                                                
admin     3004  0.0  8.1 265444 85760 ?        Sl   10:39   0:00 Rails: /var/www/redmine                                                                                
admin     3010  0.0  8.1 265444 85760 ?        Sl   10:39   0:00 Rails: /var/www/redmine                                                                                
admin     3016  0.0  9.9 282532 104400 ?       Sl   10:39   0:01 Rails: /var/www/redmine                                                                                
www-data  3026  0.0  1.6 301492 17416 ?        S    10:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
git       3042  0.0 12.8 313152 134320 ?       Sl   10:39   0:00 Rack: /home/git/gitlab                                                                                 
root      3794  0.0  0.3  71248  3628 ?        Ss   11:23   0:00 sshd: admin [priv]
admin     3797  0.0  0.1  71248  1824 ?        R    11:23   0:00 sshd: admin@pts/0
admin     3798  0.0  0.2  19428  2228 pts/0    Ss   11:23   0:00 -bash
www-data  3922  0.0  1.6 301520 17448 ?        S    11:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3926  0.0  1.6 301472 17328 ?        S    11:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3929  0.0  1.6 301472 17288 ?        S    11:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  3930  0.0  1.5 301256 16220 ?        S    11:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      4012  0.0  0.2  72552  2876 ?        S    11:38   0:00 sendmail: MTA: ./s59ECXBN022245 example.com.: user open
```

and this is the result of "free -m":

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024        962         61          0          0        196
-/+ buffers/cache:        766        257
Swap:         1024          0       1024
```

Comment: Basically there's not much you can do, gitlab [recommends at least 1gb of memory](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/requirements.md)